# Java 8 lambda expression: Group all items in sequence which satisfy the given predicate. Grouping shall have predicate as key, items as value

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Here is the sample input data and expected output. I want perform this operation 
with single iteration on the input list.

```
// input
Predicate<File> sizeP = f -> f.length() > 1_000_000; // size filter
Predicate<File> nameP = f -> f.getName().startsWith("Plot"); // name filter
List<File> fileList;
// output
// files list which satisfy the filter criteria
Map<Predicate<File>,List<File>> rulesToFiles = new HashMap<>();

// Example data
//  1. PlotPresentation.pptx-> 2 MB size      
//  2. Gen.docx-> 500 KB size
//  3. Group.docx-> 1.5 MB size
//  4. PlotDetails.docx-> 850 KB size
//  5. PlotDiagram.docx-> 5 MB size

// my map should have
Map<Predicate<File>,List<File>> rulesToFiles = new HashMap<>();
// [size-predicate]-> [PlotPresentation.pptx,Group.docx,PlotDiagram.docx]
// [name-predicate]-> [PlotPresentation.pptx,PlotDetails.docx,PlotDiagram.docx]
```

Comment: What if an item satisfies both of the predicates?

Comment: This question would be easier to read if you included more description at the beginning. Yes, we can dig through your code to try and figure out your goal, but why not explain it clearly to us at the beginning?

Comment: You are not supposed to store Predicates as a key in the Map. These are functional interfaces, they do not override equals or hashcode (and you can't do that anyway), so given `Predicate<File> size2 = f -> f.size > 1_000_000;` `size.equals(size2)` will give you false, and its likely that `containsKey` will give you false if you give another predicate with the same semantic.

Comment: @kocko Looking at the example map, it seems it should be present in both map values.

Comment: Yes, it should be present in both maps. Intent is how many files satisfy each criteria

Comment: Regarding the Alexis.C question, I may store string name instead of predicate.

Comment: @madhub: if you just want to know how many files match, use `filter(…).count()`, there is no need to populate a `Map` just to find out the count.

Comment: @Holger I need the list of items ( in this case files)

Comment: Your code is contradicting. At the beginning, you have a `size` and a `sizeAndName` filter, at the end you expect a `size` and `name` key. It makes a huge difference whether the second criteria includes the first one or whether they are disjunct.

Answer (score 2):

In order to associate useful keys with predicates, we may use a `Map`:

```
Map<String, Predicate<File>> pred=new TreeMap<>();
pred.put("size", f -> f.length() > 1_000_000);
pred.put("name", f -> f.getName().startsWith("Plot"));
```

Then we can process them like this:

```
Map<String,List<File>> rulesToFiles = 
    fileList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(f->
        pred.entrySet().stream().filter(e->e.getValue().test(f))
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.joining("+"))
    ));
```

this results in

```
 => [Gen.docx]
size => [Group.docx]
name => [PlotDetails.docx]
name+size => [PlotPresentation.pptx, PlotDiagram.docx]
```

which isn’t exactly as requested in your question but quite useful. Maybe you can live with that.

But if this doesn’t satisfy you, you may apply a post-processing to the `Map`:

```
if(rulesToFiles.getClass()!=HashMap.class)// ensure mutable Map
    rulesToFiles=new HashMap<>(rulesToFiles);

rulesToFiles.remove(""); // remove the none-matching items
List<File> nameAndSize = rulesToFiles.remove("name+size");// remove&check for common items
if(nameAndSize!=null) {// merge them
    BinaryOperator<List<File>> merger=(a,b)->
        Stream.concat(a.stream(), b.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    rulesToFiles.merge("size", nameAndSize, merger);
    rulesToFiles.merge("name", nameAndSize, merger);
}
```

result:

```
size => [Group.docx, PlotPresentation.pptx, PlotDiagram.docx]
name => [PlotDetails.docx, PlotPresentation.pptx, PlotDiagram.docx]
```

---

#### Update:

I thought it over and here’s a solution to produce a `Map` as requested, right by the `Stream` operation in the first place, so no additional operation is required. Based on the `Map<String, Predicate<File>> pred` of the first solution, use:

```
Map<String,List<File>> rulesToFiles = fileList.stream()
    .flatMap(f -> pred.entrySet().stream().filter(e->e.getValue().test(f))
        .map(e->new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey(), f)))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

Result:

```
size => [PlotPresentation.pptx, Group.docx, PlotDiagram.docx]
name => [PlotPresentation.pptx, PlotDetails.docx, PlotDiagram.docx]
```

Comment: Your update doesn't compile for me. I'm trying to figure out a fix, but it seems the compiler isn't correctly deducing the types you are working with, ultimately resulting in a `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Object,List<Object>> to Map<String,List<File>>` error.

Comment: @Duncan: sounds strange as I tried several jdks (`jdk1.8.0_05`, `jdk1.8.0_20`, `jdk1.8.0_40`), all of them compiling it flawlessly. Do you use the jdk compiler? And are no `import`s missing? The error messages can be quite distracting from the real problem, sometimes. It may help to insert explicit type arguments until the real problem has been revealed, then remove the type arguments again…

Comment: Yup, seems to be the Eclipse compiler at fault. Compiles fine with `javac`.