# Java 8 summarise by multiple predicate

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Consider the following pojo class annotated using [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) annotations

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Builder
@ToString
public class User {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Gender gender;
    private Integer age;
    private Integer points;
}
```

requirement is to get `LongSummaryStatistics` of 'points' attribute for following predicates:

1. `Predicate<User> adultMenPredicate = user -> Gender.MALE == user.getGender && user.getAge()>18`
2. `Predicate<User> adultWomenPredicate = user -> Gender.FEMALE == user.getGender && user.getAge()>18`
3. `Predicate<User> minorPredicate = user -> user.getAge()<18`

My current Implementation is :

```
private LongSummaryStatistics getPointStats(List<User> users, Predicate<User> predicate) {
    return users.stream().filter(predicate).mapToLong(User::getPoints).summaryStatistics();
}

System.out.println("point stats for adult men: " + getPointStats(users, adultMenPredicate));
System.out.println("point stats for adult women: " + getPointStats(users, adultWomenPredicate));
System.out.println("point stats for minors: " + getPointStats(users, minorPredicate));
```

Here we are iterating the users collection thrice. Is it possible to get this in just one iteration ?

Comment: Not with streams. From a computational point of view, the operation of iterating three times over the list is constant, so ignore performance issues. Keep it like it is, much more readable and testable. If you really (really) need performance, go for a for-each by constructing you own stats and if-then-else in the for-each

Answer (score 2):

I've figured out something like that:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    List<User> users = ImmutableList.of(new User("a", "s", MALE, 19, 22),
                                        new User("a", "s", MALE, 15, 49),
                                        new User("a", "s", MALE, 22, 11),
                                        new User("a", "s", FEMALE, 19, 1),
                                        new User("a", "s", MALE, 12, 22));

    Map<Type, Integer> collect = users.stream()
            .map(u -> Tuple.tuple(u, resolveType(u)))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Tuple::right, Collectors.summingInt(t -> t.left().points)));
    System.out.println(collect);
}

public static Type resolveType(final User user) {
    if (user.gender == MALE && user.age > 18) {
        return Type.ADULT_MALE;
    } else if (user.gender == FEMALE && user.age > 18) {
        return Type.ADULT_FEMALE;
    } else {
        return Type.MINOR;
    }
}

public enum Type {
    ADULT_MALE, ADULT_FEMALE, MINOR
}
```

I guess it's a balanced solution - quite efficient and readable.
I don't like if-else statements so you can replace it with Map like:

```
private static final Map<Predicate<User>, Type> predicates = ImmutableMap.of(
        user -> user.getGender() == MALE && user.getAge() >= 18, Type.ADULT_MALE,
        user -> user.getGender() == FEMALE && user.getAge() >= 18, Type.ADULT_FEMALE,
        user -> user.getAge() < 18, Type.MINOR
);

public static Type resolveType(final User user) {
    return predicates.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().test(user))
            .findFirst()
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
}
```

It prints:

```
{ADULT_MALE=33, MINOR=71, ADULT_FEMALE=1}
```

I guess you don't have to worry about performance unless you're dealing with huge collections.

// edit
Just to make it clear. My tuple implementation looks like that:

```
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Tuple<L, R> {
    public static <L, R> Tuple<L, R> tuple(L left, R right) {
        return new Tuple<>(left, right);
    }

    private final L left;
    private final R right;

    private Tuple(L left, R right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    public L left() {
        return left;
    }

    public R right() {
        return right;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do we get min max average etc which are attributes of `LongSummaryStatistics` ?

Comment: But i think we can use groupingBy instead of tuple like mentioned here :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293453/java-8-lambda-expression-group-all-items-in-sequence-which-satisfy-the-given-pr

Comment: I've already used groupingBy collector but I group by left field of the tuple. Tuple's been used here because I need access to both user and resolved type. I get the sum of points by using summingInt nested collector. Take a look at Collectors class. There are many collectors that might be helpful for you like: averagingInt, minBy, maxBy etc.

Comment: The `Tuple` type is as obsolete as the `.map` step that forces its necessity. Just use `users.stream()  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(u -> resolveType(u), Collectors.summingInt( User::getPoints)))` (or `users.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(u->resolveType(u), Collectors.summarizingLong(User::getPoints)))` to get the `LongSummaryStatistics`). Besides that, I wouldn’t use Streams in `resolveType`, but just `return user.getAge() < 18? Type.MINOR: user.getGender() == MALE? Type.ADULT_MALE: Type.ADULT_FEMALE;` Note that checking `<18` first removes the need for checking `>=18` twice…

Comment: @Holger: yup you're right. I just got used to using tuples (scala). Tuple + map aren't necessary in this case but when you use tuples it makes code a little bit more readable (at least for me). Checking <18 first makes sense only when you know that most Users are <18. In case majority are ADULT_MALE I would still check <18 last. resolveType can either use if statements or stream. I know that stream might be slightly less efficient here but I rather prefer functional style so in case I add for instance call to external service I can still make it parallel by switching stream to parallelStream.

Comment: Even if the majority is `ADULT_MALE`, you’re still unavoidably checking the `>=18` condition then, as that’s a requirement. Since you *always* have to compare with `18`, there is no disadvantage in comparing with `18` first. Comparing with `18` first will never perform worse than the other approach, but faster for underage users.